# VBA Excel: How to select an entired row in a table?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with a table and I want to select the entired row in the table according to the selection,

using VBA.

Answer (score 3):

This code is used to select the entire row of the active cell.

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
```